# What is the good code style for scala when calling a method of an object

Tags: scala

I don't know how to choose between two code style for a scala project, when calling a method from an object.

code style 1

```
import com.socgen.bsc.sqd.per.Load._ 
val pAndRDf: DataFrame = loadPandR(sqdDate)
```

code style 2

```
import com.socgen.bsc.sqd.per.Load
val pAndRDf: DataFrame = Load.loadPandR(sqdDate)
```

I would like to know which one is better or between these two styles, they are the same and we can choose whatever we like.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer *style 2*, especially if the name of the object is so short. If you have a longer name you can also add a substitution, like:$

```
import com.socgen.bsc.sqd.per.{LongComplexLoad => LCL}
val pAndRDf: DataFrame = LCL.loadPandR(sqdDate)
```

There is another style I usually do if I am in control. That is to use `trait`s instead of `object`s.

```
class MyClass extends Load {

   val pAndRDf: DataFrame = loadPandR(sqdDate)
   ...
}
```

This has the advantage that you see what you use in the class description. If the list gets too long it is also an indication that you may think about *Separation of Concerns*.

There is also a discussion about that on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/bb2dqt/question_is_it_better_to_put_helper_methods_in_a/)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on you style, but , for me if you can minimize the use of  "_" would be great.

And i would use like this:

```
import com.socgen.bsc.sqd.per.Load.loadPandR
val pAndRDf: DataFrame = loadPandR(sqdDate)
```

Edited

Comment: I think you have a type - should not be `import com.socgen.bsc.sqd.per.loadPandR`?

Comment: Yes what you said @pme

Answer (score 0):

Best idea is to go with option 2 where possible. Have modified your value name too (as I personally think it’s more readable).

```
import com.socgen.bsc.sqd.per.Load
val dfPAndR: DataFrame = Load.loadPandR(sqdDate)
```

Avoid ambiguous imports where possible. It can make it harder to debug your code, increases the chances of accidentally importing two `Load` objects (if you’re doing another ambiguous import somewhere) and means you’re importing a lot of stuff that you don’t need, potentially causing bloat.

If you need to import multiple things then stick to curly brace `import com.org.package.{Load, Write}`.

I’d (personally) also change the value name. Most of us read left to right, so know you know it’s a dataframe first, then what value it is.

It’s a small change, but can help speed up debugging. Especially if you have an `rddPAndR` later on (for instance).